# In an operating system, who is responsible for thread cancellation?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, cancellation

In a multithreading environment, threads can be cancelled in one of two ways : through **asynchronous cancellation** or **deferred cancellation**. 
Since I have read in a reference textbook that in a two-level model for multithreading, a user thread library is responsible for threads scheduling, I was wondering *who is responsible for thread cancellation in an operating system ?*

Is it also the user thread library ?

This doesn't sound like a very bright idea to me since the library could very well do pretty much whatever it wants and this seems like a huge design flaw to me. (You could end up with unkillable threads wiping your entire disk !)

Could it be the OS itself ?

Then again, the OS might not be even be aware of threads (for example in a Many-to-One model), so it would end up not being able to recognize such threads.

Anyway, any enlightenment is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends upon how threads are implemented. If, as you suggest, threads are created through a user library, then killing the process kills the threads. Depending upon the operating system, the library might be able to implement cleanup of the threads (rather than a sudden death).

If the threads are implemented in the OS kernel, the operating system must handle the thread termination.

Comment: If I'm getting this correctly, threads are cancelled by the entity that created them ?

Answer (score 0):

"Threads wiping your hard disk" are a non-issue. User-mode threads can do just as much as the main thread. Besides, the OS can usually kill the whole user process without caring about its internal details, so it's irrelevant if those details involved user-mode threads.

Of course, when the OS is responsible for threads in a process, it has to stop those threads before removing the process. The OS can't schedule those threads anymore, obviously, as their code dies with the address space of the stopped process.